# How to setup VLC's stereo audio mode to left as default

Tags: mac, vlc-media-player

I'm using Mac and can't find how to setup VLC's stereo audio mode to left as default. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC Prefs, click 'Show All', bottom left, then in the first pane you see in there, set Stereo audio output mode to Left, then Save.
Relaunch to activate.

[image]

Comment: WTFF, I thought I have checked every single button but failed to notice "Show All". I feel so comfortable now with the audio mode change to left as default. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Thank you. I came here for this exact problem, and you absolutely saved my day!    
'Show all' - Yeah, who knew...